# How do I create a quiz app with three different answer modes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a quiz app which should feature 5 questions, chosen randomly from a bank of questions. But, the there should be three different ways of answering the questions :

1. At least one should use radio buttons
2. At least one should use a drop down
3. At least one should use text input

How do I create this please ? I don't have a JS file yet, I don't mind you creating a JS file.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,regular,500,600,700,800,900);
:root {
    --background: rgb(29, 26, 26);
    --text-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--background);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.quiz-container {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.header h3 {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: 30px;
}

.question-tog {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

button {
    padding: 8px 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

i {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Interactive Quiz App</title>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/quiz/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="quiz-container">
        <div class="header"><h3>Interactive Quiz App</h3></div>

        <div class="quiz">
            
        </div>

        <div class="question-tog">
            <button class="prev"> <span>Prev</span> <i class='bx bx-left-arrow-alt'></i></button>
            <button class="next"> <span>Next</span> <i class='bx bx-right-arrow-alt'></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should try writing some code and come back when it doesn't work.

Comment: There's no one coming to write the JS for you.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't figured out how I am going to do it yet

Comment: @tborges Chill man, I just need someone who'd guide me. I am still a JS beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create the following quiz you need to use js arrays. Which will store the set of questions to choose randomly. Another thing is you need to use js modules to send data across pages. And that is how you can do it.

I'd rather suggest you to use php sessions instead they are way more simpler and easier to word with.

Comment: I have to use Javascript  :(

Comment: Then bro. Go and start writing some code. In my opinion we are here to help you. Not to work for you. In case you got struck somewhere while coding you are always welcome here.